# Flutter Drawer Photo not working- 'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 25 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I wanna show the profile photo in drawer header but it shows error
**'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 25 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.**

Firebase give profile photo URL to the variable, but the error shows the variable is null

I tried to solve this error in many ways, but unfortunately couldn't fix it

````
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fivetagsmobileapp/constant.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_restart/flutter_restart.dart';

class Drwr extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrwrState createState() => _DrwrState();
}

class _DrwrState extends State<Drwr> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String profilePhoto;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final User user = _auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      profilePhoto = documentSnapshot.data()["profileURL"];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        canvasColor: blueLight,
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(150),
        ),
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: blueLightUnselected,
                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: blueLight, spreadRadius: 1)],
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30.0,
                      foregroundImage: NetworkImage(profilePhoto),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a default image? In case the "profilePhoto" is null